# What is the optimal way to lnurl-pay without running a ln node?

Tags: lightning-network

I am working on a service that would receive payments through lightning and would need to use a static lnurl-pay QR code (no screen available). When payment is received I would like some automated action to occur (like flip a switch, I would check for payment via api + polling, websockets or anything like that).

I am having a difficult time understanding what is the minimum I need to setup the payment address that I can then monitor when is it paid. I would like to avoid having to run my own lightning node, as that brings additional server management + funding requirements.

Any suggestions where to start?

Answer (score 2):

The LNBits project has many good integration extensions, but you would need an LNBits instance to use that. With LNBits it's possible to use an instance run by someone else (whom you trust).